# How to add two key values and display in another keyvalue dynamically in json using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I had the following json

```
var data = {
    "total": "",
    "scores": [{
        "subject": "maths",
        "marks": "50"
    }, {
        "subject": "science",
        "marks": "75"
    }]
};
```

Now in the total ,value should be 125 which should be updated automatically.
Also in the scores keys ,the values will be coming dynamically.So all the marks should be added automatically and displayed in total.
So how can I do this with any javascript .
Can someone help me.
Thanks!

Expected

```
var data = {
    "total": "125",
    "scores": [{
        "subject": "maths",
        "marks": "50"
    }, {
        "subject": "science",
        "marks": "75"
    }]
};
```

Comment: The only way is `iteration`. Iterate your array of objects and calculate

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce()` to calculate total and then assign it to data.total

```js
var data = {
  "total": "",
  "scores": [{
    "subject": "maths",
    "marks": "50"
  }, {
    "subject": "science",
    "marks": "75"
  }]
}

var total = data.scores.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + parseInt(b.marks);
}, 0)

data.total = total;
console.log(data)
```

Comment: this is not really dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

You could apply a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters) and reduce the values from scores.

```js
var data = {
        get total() {
            return this.scores.reduce(function (r, a) { return r + +a.marks; }, 0)
        },
        scores: [{ subject: "maths", marks: "50" }, { subject: "science", marks: "75" }]
    };

console.log(data.total);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own class:

```
function Data()
{
    this.scores = [];
    this.total = 0;

    this.addScore = function(subject ,marks) {
        var score = { "subject" : subject ,"marks" : marks };

        this.scores.push(score);
        this.total += marks;
    }

    this.stringify = function() {
        return JSON.stringify(this);
    }
}

var data = new Data();

data.addScore("maths",50);
console.log( data.stringify() );
data.addScore("science",75);
console.log( data.stringify() );
```

Output:

```
{"scores":[{"subject":"maths","marks":50}],"total":50}
{"scores":[{"subject":"maths","marks":50},{"subject":"science","marks":75}],"total":125}
```

You can use, object itself or the JSON string. Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

A simple for loop should suffice.

```js
let data = {
  "total": "",
  "scores": [{
    "subject": "maths",
    "marks": "50"
  }, {
    "subject": "science",
    "marks": "75"
  }]
};

for (let i in data.scores)
  data.total = ((parseInt(data.total) || 0) + parseInt(data.scores[i].marks)).toString();

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a ES 2015 Solution:

```
var result = 0;

for (let score of data.scores){
    result += parseInt(score.marks);
}

data.total = result;
```

And the same can be achieved with older JavaScript

```
result = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < data.scores.length; i++) {
    result += parseInt(data.scores[i].marks);
}

data.total = result;
```

You should able to fit this code snippets into your code. Just remember not to use `for .. in`, as it is deprecated due to https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in

Hope I could help

**Edit:** It seems that one some other MDM page about for .. in, that it is not stated as deprecated. So sorry about that.

Comment: `for ... in` is fine... https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: Strange. The Site I got from MDM statet is as deprecated. Just wanted to include that, to make sure he doesn't use deprecated code, since I don't consider that good practice.

Comment: you were looking at `for each ... in`

Comment: I see. Didn't know there were 2 different for .. in in JavaScript (I'm usually using jQuery's for each). Thank you for telling me :)